# JavaFX Pong Vertical Game issues

Tags: java, networking, javafx, collision-detection, game-physics

Hello dear `stackoverflow` users, I'm just exhausted of trying **everything** so far, can you pretty please help me with 2 issues at the game I'm developing ?

Let's get started, I will try to explain **as clear as I can**.

Here's my code so far:

```
WIN_H = 600
WIN_W = 450
BAT_W = 100
BAT_H = 20
BallRadius = 10

//Check against the ball if is touching the Y-0 or Y-WIN_H axis
ballUp = true //Boolean to check against the Y-axis like on the Tutorial.


//Check against the BATs on Yaxis

if(ball.getTranslateY + BallRadius = 0)
  restartGame();

if(ball.getTranslateY() + BallRadius = WIN_H - BAT_HEIGHT
&& ball.getTranslateX() + BallRadius >= bat.getTranslateX()
&& ball.getTranslateX() - BallRadius <= bat.getTranslateX() - BAT_WIDTH

&& ball.getTranslateX() + BallRadius >= bat2.getTranslateX()
&& ball.getTranslateX() - BallRadius <= bat2.getTranslateX() - BAT_WIDTH)
ballUp = true;

//Check against the Y (WIN_H) axis - bottom & 0 means top.
if(ball.getTranslateY() + BallRadius = WIN_H)
ballUp = true;
```

I'm making a *Vertical* `Ping-Pong` game with **2 Bats** and **1 Ball**, pretty mainstream so far,inspired from this **tutorial** , my *"changed"* code is at 13:31 [here](https://youtu.be/g7p67rvYN5U) ,  my problems are the followings :

- I don't know how to make the Player 2's bat on top to have collision
  detection for the ball ( **bottom is working very well**).
- I don't know how to implement Multiplayer network connection between two player on a LAN (**I can learn tho'**). I researched some libraries but so far NettyIO seems my path. At this field of problem I just want to ask you if:

  1. Is this **possible** and reliable? (check the image bellow, StreamBuffer between players and ball's movement)
  2. Which **"path"** you recommend me to choose for Net part ?

I'm sorry if I wasn't clear enough, I just want **Guideness** from somebody willing to help me with 1-2 Ideas, *Guide me please*.

[image]

**Have a nice day!**

P.S: *Even if you believe that my question isn't well formatted please format it and please don't remove it, I just can be relaxed until I solve my* **mystery :(**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Found the solution for the first issue !!!**

I've made a method with `checkTop()` and I put it after the `//Check against top`

```
checkTop(){
if(ball.getTranslateY() + BallRadius = 0 + BAT2_HEIGHT*2
&& ball.getTranslateX() + BallRadius >= bat2.getTranslateX()
&& ball.getTranslateX() - BallRadius <= bat2.getTranslateX() - BAT_WIDTH

}

//and I set my top Bat like this
BAT2.setTranslateX((WIN_H-WIN_H)+WIN_H/2);
BAT2.setTranslateY(0+BAT_HEIGHT*2);
```

I also removed the Top-Bat declaration in the `if statements` of c*hecking against the bats*.

Now the collision with the Top bat works very well!

I still have an issue with the Networking part, how should I implement it? Wich library to choose for a "**starter junior**" ? It will work with half screens buffering or you , guys, got a better idea?

*Anticipate thanks!*